# Как достать рейтинг компании с яндекс-карты?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как вывести на сайте рейтинг компании? В апи не нашел нужного метода.

Answer (score 1):

Для сайта лучше использовать виджеты Яндекса, которые сразу с аккуратной вёрсткой и ссылкой на Карты покажут рейтинг.

Вот пример:

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:152px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/226327670406?size=m"></iframe></div>
```

В этом коде id организации подставляется в src, можно также сделать вместо этого размер s (150x104px)

Или же можно вставить сразу виджет с отзывами.

Код можно скопировать прямо на Яндекс.Картах - выбираете свою организацию, открываете в боковом меню "Поделиться" (иконка = в правом углу экрана) и там будет код.

Comment: Нужно сделать в дизайне, который предоставил клиент.

Comment: Такой возможности в API нет, увы

Answer (score 0):

В последней версии API Яндекс.Карт добавлен Метод [findOrganization()](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization-docpage/), который позволяет программно открыть карточку конкретной организации по её id.

Это открыло доступ ко множеству данных организаций, получаемых в свойствах геообъекта.
Для вашего вопроса это возможность получить рейтинг.

Следующий код выдаст в консоль всё дерево свойств объекта и рейтинг в частности:

```
ymaps.findOrganization('1671141286').then(
function (orgGeoObject) {
console.log('Структура данных огранизации:');
console.log(orgGeoObject.properties);
console.log('-------------------------------');

myMap.geoObjects.add(orgGeoObject);
orgGeoObject.balloon.open();
var rating = orgGeoObject.properties.get('rating');
console.log('Рейтинг:');
console.log('Оценок: ' + rating.ratings);
console.log('Обзоров: ' + rating.reviews);
console.log('Балл: ' + rating.score);
}
)
```

Comment: Решение может сломаться в любой момент, так как набор опций и их доступность средствами API в документации не описаны, то есть они не являются частью публичного  API и обратная совместимость для них не гарантирована. Завтра Яндекс может поменять набор полей или их названия и всё сломается.

Comment: Кроме того, если доставать данные таким образом без показа карты и отображать в своём дизайне, это будет нарушением условий использования API и может привести к бану.